# Trouble getting Alexa slot value is AWS Lamba function

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created an intent in Alexa console and corresponding function in AWS Lambda (Javascript) and it's working for the most part as expected. However I can't seem to gather the slot values.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
  alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;

  let config = new Map();
  let character = this.event.request.intent.slots.character.value;
  if (!character)
    character = 'default';

  let handlers = getHandlers(config);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};
```

The error I'm receiving in the Alexa test is mostly not helpful and I'm generally finding debugging Alexa quite painful. I have tried testing directly from within Lambda and passing a JSON payload but I'm unsure if this would work anyway.

Can someone comment on whether `this.event.request.intent.slots.character.value;` would be correct? I can't see this on official AWS pages but in other peoples' examples.

Lastly, the payload from Alexa test has this included:

```
"request": {
                        "type": "IntentRequest",
                        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.43808260-5aaa-4837-9f28-4eaccb7c9b3c",
                        "timestamp": "2018-05-31T00:49:08Z",
                        "locale": "en-AU",
                        "intent": {
                            "name": "playSeinfeldQuoteIntent",
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                            "slots": {
                                "character": {
                                    "name": "character",
                                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                                },
                                "position": {
                                    "name": "position",
                                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I would have expected it to have the values on the slots included here but they're not so this may be the issue.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Edit: I found that I was capturing the values OK but the first letter of each variable was being capitalised. I guess because they are peoples' names Alexa is capitalising them. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: You are capturing right but the value is not available to capture. Does the character slot take list of items for e.g. jerry, elaine etc. the problem seems to be not at the lambda side but at the voice interface side.

Comment: I first letter of each character was being capitalised. I have it working now. Thanks